# form submit fails to do as I want it to

Tags: php, javascript, forms

```
<?=form_open('register');?> 
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="register_name">Username : </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="register_name" readonly="true" value="<?=$_POST['username']?>"/></td>                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="register_email">Email:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="register_email" readonly="true" value="<?=$_POST['email']?>"/></td>                
                </tr>                
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="register_password">Password:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="register_password" readonly="true" value="<?=$_POST['password']?>"/></td>                
                </tr>               
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="return true;"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>                     
                        <input type="submit" value="Edit" onclick="window.location.replace('http://localhost/index.php?username='<?=$_POST['email']?>'&email='<?=$_POST['email']?>');return true;"/></td>                    
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?=form_close()?>
```

I have got an error at the final "input type=submit" as it is odd to me that after I press the button, it proceed further action (register) instead of returning back to the index page. Is the URL I use incorrect ?
(I would like to return back the main page with the information for GETs)

UPDATE

I have a registration form (the main index page) in which the user is to fill in with username and password along with his email address. After he presses submit, he will be directed to Confirm page in which there is also a button to direct him back to the main page. The confirm page only rewrites his filled information from the index page. If he wants to change any, he can press the EDIT button. Once he presses it, I would like the information such as username and email address to still be existing on the index page. This is a little tricky part for newbies like me. I would like to learn how you deal with this. The above code is what I have tried without any luck at all because it registers when I press any of the two buttons.

Comment: Try `return false;` at the end instead of `return true;` (false will cancel the default action of the submit button).

Comment: Do you want to submit the page to 'register' or 'index'? Right now you're telling it to do conflicting things. If you want to post to index, then index should be your target. Mind you, it almost looks like you're confusing server side code with client side code, as the PHP will be evaluated before the user ever sees the form (which doesn't make sense if this was a registration form, as you wouldn't have that data yet).

Comment: @nnnnnn `preventDefault()` should be preferred over `return false;` as the latter can have unintended consequences (such as multiple event handlers).

Comment: Thanks n and Kitsune, @Kitusne, yes that is the part I don't know yet about Server script and Clien script. Information good to learn!

Comment: Please read my UPDATE for more detail about what I am doing

Comment: In your code, the value of `window.location.replace` will always have an empty `username=` and `email=` as $_POST is populated when the *current* page is loading. In this case, you should just point the form towards index.php, and let the browser automatically post the data for you (or GET, as you're doing with that URL).

Comment: Thanks, what do you actually mean ? replace('http://localhost/index.php?......); What is .....I need to fill in?

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure why you are using a submit button here if you don't want to submit the page.

i see two options, make the

```
<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="window.location.replace('http://localhost/index.php?username='<?=$_POST['email']?>'&email='<?=$_POST['email']?>');return true;"/>
```

or return false in on submit action

```
<input type="submit" value="Edit" onclick="window.location.replace('http://localhost/index.php?username='<?=$_POST['email']?>'&email='<?=$_POST['email']?>');return false;"/>
```